# Best way to generate a custom field across a Pandas dataframe using other columns which vary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to generate a personal identifier variable across a dataframe which carries many people. This would exist of 10 characters of their surname, if their surname is under 10 characters it would fill those cells with '2'.

i.e. `people['surname'].astype(str).str[0] + people['surname'].astype(str).str[1]`

What is the most effective way to do this? I have come from other languages where I would use for loops but I understand that is less effective especially with big dataframes, when I can use vectors and other things. Any advice would be hugely appreciated please as I want to improve habits/efficiency.

An example of my data would be:
people:

firstname, surname, dob,

```
bob, jobs, 2000-01-04
jim, jobsworth, 2000-01-02
rob, jobbington, 2000-01-03
cob, jobsalotverylongname, 2000-01-01
```

Comment: Can yo uadd expected output?

Comment: Sure - 
jobs999999 for the first row with just the surname, but with dob added too I would need to parse the dob string to get the month, day and year out - I'm happy to think about how I need to do that, I just know it is a little too complex to try use an equals statement here and + the character numbers

Comment: Added answer, I hope understand what need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.ljust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html), get first 10 values by indexing `str[:10]` with convert column `dob` to datetimes and extract `year, month, day`s to new columns:

```
df['surname'] = df['surname'].str.ljust(10, '9').str[:10]
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'])
df['y'] = df['dob'].dt.year
df['m'] = df['dob'].dt.month
df['d'] = df['dob'].dt.day
print (df)
  firstname     surname        dob     y  m  d
0       bob  jobs999999 2000-01-04  2000  1  4
1       jim  jobsworth9 2000-01-02  2000  1  2
2       rob  jobbington 2000-01-03  2000  1  3
3       cob  jobsalotve 2000-01-01  2000  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes using pandas functions on entrire columns is much more efficient than looping over the rows.

As a first answer, I would suggest this:
Add a bunch of `'2'`s to the surname, then select the first 10 characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I was considering it but I have to do some string parsing for the date of birth and probably some other fields, I think learning how to use vectorize or other functions would help me going forwards if I have similar work to do like this